# Why doesn't SameText work?

Tags: string, delphi, text, case

Why does

```
if SameText(ListBox1.Items[i],Edit1.Text)=true then
```

not work? It is case-sensitive (strings have different cases), but must be not. The strings are unicode. It works if the strings have the same cases.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `=true` part!!

Comment: You have made a silly mistake, somewhere. What, exactly, is `ListBox1.Items[i]`, and what, exactly, is `Edit1.Text`?

Comment: What kind of a mistake could I make? Edit1.Text - a text and ListBox1.Items[i] - a text too.

Comment: It does work.  You just aren't passing two identical strings.

Comment: Since I know these two functions to work in every normal instance, you *have* to make a silly mistake somewhere...

Comment: @Nick and Andreas, your insights are great, you should have those posted as answers

Comment: I am passing the same text. "Ab" is in the Edit. "ab" is in the Item of the List Box (it is unicode instead of "ab/Ab").

Comment: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=22016

Comment: @Boris Treukhov , is there a way to compare normally?

Comment: Generally speaking, no. For example, А and A are different characters and it's hard to say whether they should be treated as equal.  But for the user input rule of thumb is to use AnsiCompareXXXX functions instead of CompareXXXX - that's enough in most cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to *SysUtils.pas* (Delphi-XE), **SameText** *"has the same 8-bit limitations as **CompareText**"*, and in **CompareText** *"the compare operation is based on the 8-bit ordinal value of each character, after converting 'a'..'z' to 'A'..'Z', and is not affected by the current user locale."*

So it seems that you are trying to compare some characters that are outside the 8 bit range.

*Edit: you should try AnsiSameText.*

Comment: "Internally, AnsiSameText() uses the Win32 API CompareStringW() function (on 
 Windows platforms anyway) to handle everything." - https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=22016